# Full name regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, whitespace

I know there are lots of similar questions, but I couldn't find my case anywhere.

I'm trying to write a **Full Name RegEx** in Ruby on Rails user model.
It should validate that first name and last name are filled with one whitespace. Both of the names should contain **at least 2 characters** (ex: Li Ma).

As a bonus, but not necessary I would like to trim the whitespaces to one character in case that user will mistype and enter more than one whitespace (ex: Li    Ma will be trimmed to Li Ma)
Currently I'm validating it like that (**Warning: It might be incorrect**):

```
validates :name,
        presence: true,
        length: {
            maximum: 64,
            minimum: 5,
            message: 'must be a minimum: 5 letters and a maximum: 64 letters'},
        format: {
            # Full Name RegEx
            with: /[\w\-\']+([\s]+[\w\-\']){1}/
        }
```

This works for me, but doesn't check for minimum 2 characters for each name (ex: Peter P is now correct). This also accepts multiple whitespaces which is not good (ex: Peter    P)

I know that this problem of identifying names is very culture-centric and it might be not a proper way to validate full name (maybe there are people with one character name), but this is currently a requirement.

I don't want to split this field to 2 different fields First name and Last name as it will complicate user interface.

Comment: What about last names with consists of more that one word like “Van Damme”?

Comment: I do believe it's spelled "Van Damage".

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention. It may contain more than 2 words, but not less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the following `regex`:

`/([\w\-\']{2,})([\s]+)([\w\-\']{2,})/`

and replace with: (assuming it supports capturing groups)

`'\1 \3'` or `$1 $3`   whatever the syntax is:

It gets rid of extra whitespaces and only keeps one, as you wanted.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/oQ6aO7

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for... But where do I include '\1 \3'? Should it be part of regex?

Comment: It would be in the part that you replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = subject.gsub(/\A(?=[\w' -]{5,64})([\w'-]{2,})([\s]{1})\s*?([\w'-]{2,})\Z/, '\1\2\3')
```

http://regex101.com/r/dT1fJ4

```
Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=[\w' -]{5,64})»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[\w' -]{5,64}»
      Between 5 and 64 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{5,64}»
      A word character (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»
      The character “'” «'»
      The character “ ” « »
      The character “-” «-»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([\w'-]{2,})»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[\w'-]{2,}»
      Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{2,}»
      A word character (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»
      The character “'” «'»
      The character “-” «-»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([\s]{1})»
   Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «[\s]{1}»
      Exactly 1 times «{1}»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «([\w'-]{2,})»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[\w'-]{2,}»
      Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{2,}»
      A word character (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»
      The character “'” «'»
      The character “-” «-»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```